# Improve Search Result Speed

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, cache, search

How to improve search result speed?

Comment: While you could cache search result pages think twice before doing that - it's an essentially infinite source of cache so if people use search a lot make sure you have sufficient space to store it.

Comment: @JonathanHussey Thanks! How much space I should prepare? Is there some link I can check about cache search result?

Comment: Have a look at reports -> search terms in admin for an idea of the number of different results pages you are likely to have to cache.  Perhaps assume something along the lines of 100KB storage capacity per page (that is likely over estimating by some margin), multiply the number of search terms by that to get estimated cache storage capacity needed just for search.  Then you need a means by which to actually cache the search results pages, probably Varnish of a FPC solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you heard about solr.

“SolrTM is the popular, blazing fast open source enterprise search platform from the Apache LuceneTM project. Its major features include powerful full-text search, hit highlighting, faceted search, near real-time indexing, dynamic clustering, database integration, rich document (e.g., Word, PDF) handling, and geospatial search. Solr is highly reliable, scalable and fault tolerant, providing distributed indexing, replication and load-balanced querying, automated failover and recovery, centralized configuration and more. Solr powers the search and navigation features of many of the world’s largest internet sites.”

Check this following link and let it go... ! All the best buddy.

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/install-apache-solr/

Answer (score 1):

Well there's your problem, you're using Sphinx, not as accurate or optimized as Solr which should be your first step. You need to switch out your search engine, Solarium is a good extension. Best to have a separate Solr server, all very simple on cloud architecture, not so on fixed hardware.